# Custom KeyDeserializer

Tags: java, jackson, kotlin

I have a use case where I need a custom `KeyDeserializer`. The following works but feel wrong (it's Kotlin but should be pretty readable for Java folk):

```
class KeepMapKeyDeserializer : KeyDeserializer() {
    // In reality this is a single executable-wide instance
    val mapper = ObjectMapper()
    override fun deserializeKey(key: String, ctxt: DeserializationContext): ColumnId<*> {
        return mapper.readValue(key, ColumnId::class.java)
    }
}
```

It feels odd to use an `ObjectMapper` directly in the `deserializeKey` method but I can't find any way to use the `DeserializationContext` that passed to that method. For example, using `ctxt.parser.readValueAs(ColumnId::class.java)` doesn't work nor do more verbose options like:

```
val colIdType = ctxt.typeFactory.constructType(ColumnId::class.java)
val deserializer = ctxt.findRootValueDeserializer(colIdType)
return deserializer.deserialize(ctxt.parser, ctxt) as ColumnId<*>
```

Is this really the right way to go about things?

Note, a serialized `ColumnId` looks like this: `{"name":"c1","clazz":"kotlin.String"}`

Comment: Could you please add a example of your keys (i.e. the "column ID" serialized format)?

Comment: @olivierlemasle added the serialized format. It's just basic JSON and serializes and deserializes with `ObjectMapper` without issues.

Comment: Ok, so in that case (where the key is a plain JSON object), I think you did it the right way. I was thinking about KeySerializers where the key is just a string with a custom format like in https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-joda/blob/master/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/joda/deser/key/DateTimeKeyDeserializer.java

Comment: Thanks @olivierlemasle